# PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, pattern-matching, sql-like

I have been seeing quite a large variation in response times regarding `LIKE` queries to a particular table in my database. Sometimes I will get results within 200-400 ms (very acceptable) but other times it might take as much as 30 seconds to return results.

I understand that `LIKE` queries are very resource intensive but I just don't understand why there would be such a large difference in response times. I have built a btree index on the `owner1` field but I don't think it helps with `LIKE` queries. Anyone have any ideas?

Sample SQL:

```
SELECT gid, owner1 FORM parcels
WHERE owner1 ILIKE '%someones name%' LIMIT 10
```

I've also tried:

```
SELECT gid, owner1 FROM parcels
WHERE lower(owner1) LIKE lower('%someones name%') LIMIT 10
```

And:

```
SELECT gid, owner1 FROM parcels
WHERE lower(owner1) LIKE lower('someones name%') LIMIT 10
```

With similar results.
Table Row Count: about 95,000.

Answer (score 390, accepted):

#### FTS does not support `LIKE`

The [previously accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1566769/939860) was incorrect. [Full Text Search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html) with its full text indexes is **not** for the `LIKE` operator at all, it has its own operators and doesn't work for arbitrary strings. It operates on *words* based on dictionaries and stemming. It *does* support *prefix matching for words*, but not with the `LIKE` operator:

- [Get partial match from GIN indexed TSVECTOR column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/157982/3684)

### Trigram index for `LIKE`

Install the additional module [**`pg_trgm`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) which provides operator classes for [GIN and GiST trigram indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28976555/939860) to support **all `LIKE` and `ILIKE` patterns**, not just left-anchored ones:

Example index:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_col_gin_trgm_idx  ON tbl USING gin  (col gin_trgm_ops);
```

Or:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_col_gist_trgm_idx ON tbl USING gist (col gist_trgm_ops);
```

- [Difference between GiST and GIN index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975517/difference-between-gist-and-gin-index/28976555#28976555)

Example query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col LIKE 'foo%';
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col LIKE '%foo%';   -- works with leading wildcard, too
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col ILIKE '%foo%';  -- works case insensitively as well
```

#### Trigrams? What about shorter strings?

Words with **less than 3 letters** in indexed values still work. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.44.5)

> Each word is considered to have two spaces prefixed and one space
> suffixed when determining the set of trigrams contained in the string.

And search patterns with less than 3 letters? [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.44.7)

> For both `LIKE` and regular-expression searches, keep in mind that a
> pattern with no extractable trigrams will degenerate to a full-index scan.

Meaning, that index / bitmap index scans still work (query plans for prepared statement won't break), it just won't buy you better performance. Typically no big loss, since 1- or 2-letter strings are hardly selective (more than a few percent of the underlying table matches) and index support would not improve performance (much) to begin with, because a full table scan is faster.

#### Prefix matching

Search patterns with no leading wildcard: `col LIKE 'foo%'`.

##### `^@` operator / `starts_with()` function

Quoting the [release notes of **Postgres 11**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/release-11.html#id-1.11.6.22.5.3.4.3):

> Add prefix-match operator text ^@ text, which is supported by SP-GiST
> (Ildus Kurbangaliev)
>
> This is similar to using var LIKE 'word%' with a btree index, but it
> is more efficient.

Example query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col ^@ 'foo';  -- no added wildcard
```

But the potential of operator and function stays limited until [planner support is improved in **Postgres 15**](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/232599.1633800229%40sss.pgh.pa.us) and the [`^@` operator is documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) properly. The [release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/release-15.html#id-1.11.6.5.5.3.4):

> Allow the `^@` starts-with operator and the `starts_with()` function to
> use btree indexes if using the C collation (Tom Lane)
>
> Previously these could only use [SP-GiST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/spgist.html) indexes.

##### `COLLATE "C"`

Since Postgres 9.1, an index with `COLLATE "C"` provides the same functionality as the operator class `text_pattern_ops` described below. See:

- [Is there a difference between text_pattern_ops and COLLATE "C"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/291250/3684)

Example index:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_col_text_collate_c_idx ON tbl(col COLLATE "C");
```

##### `text_pattern_ops` (original answer)

For just **left-anchored** patterns (no leading wildcard) you get the optimum with a suitable [operator class](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-opclass.html) for a btree index: `text_pattern_ops` or `varchar_pattern_ops`. Both built-in features of standard Postgres, no additional module needed. Similar performance, but much smaller index.

Example index:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_col_text_pattern_ops_idx ON tbl(col text_pattern_ops);
```

Example query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col LIKE 'foo%';  -- no leading wildcard
```

*Or*, if you should be running your database with the *'C'* locale (effectively *no* locale), then everything is sorted according to byte order anyway and a plain btree index with default operator class does the job.

#### Further reading

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)
- [How is LIKE implemented?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10856/3684)
- [Finding similar strings with PostgreSQL quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249635/finding-similar-strings-with-postgresql-quickly/11250001#11250001)

Comment: With no leading wildcard on a table of 500K lines, gin index with gin_trgm_ops appears being 10 times faster than btree

Comment: @nicolas: The comparison depends on many variables. Key length, data distribution, pattern length, possible index only scan ... And most importantly: Postgres version. GIN indexes have been improved substantially in pg 9.4 and 9.5. An the new version of pg_trgm (to be released with pg 9.6) is going to bring more improvements.

Comment: If I got the docs right, with `pg_trgm` you need query string of at least 3 characters in length, for example `fo%` would not hit index but do a scan instead. Something to note.

Comment: @TuukkaMustonen: Good point. Well, (bitmap) index scans still *work*, they just won't buy you better performance. I added some clarification above.

Comment: Could the `^@` operator and the `starts_with()` string function get the same advantage as the left-anchored `LIKE`?

Comment: @КонстантинВан: They actually do with Postgres 15 (currently RC). Consider updates to my answer.

Comment: and for suffix in (LIKE '%blabla';) what is the best index to use ?

Comment: @Sido4odus A trigram index also covers that. Or, more efficiently for just this case, an expression index on the reversed string column. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62785629/939860 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/68402137/939860. Or start a new question with your specifics.

Comment: Ok, I see. I wonder if using LOWER before REVERSE will help improve query performance ? And how ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've posted a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74409202/470749

Answer (score 11):

Possibly the fast ones are anchored patterns with case-sensitive like that can use indexes. i.e. there is no wild card at the beginning of the match string so the executor can use an index range scan. ([the relevant comment in the docs is here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/indexes-types.html)) Lower and ilike will also lose your ability to use the index unless you specifically create an index for that purpose (see [functional indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/indexes-expressional.html)).

If you want to search for string in the middle of the field, you should look into [full text](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/textsearch.html) or [trigram indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/pgtrgm.html). First of them is in Postgres core, the other is available in the contrib modules.

Comment: I hadn't thought about creating an index on the lowercase value of the field.  That way I can convert the query text to lowercase on the backend before querying.

Answer (score 7):

I recently had a similar issue with a table containing 200000 records and I need to do repeated LIKE queries. In my case, the string being search was fixed. Other fields varied. Because that, I was able to rewrite:

```
SELECT owner1 FROM parcels
WHERE lower(owner1) LIKE lower('%someones name%');
```

as

```
CREATE INDEX ix_parcels ON parcels(position(lower('someones name') in lower(owner1)));

SELECT owner1 FROM parcels
WHERE position(lower('someones name') in lower(owner1)) > 0;
```

I was delighted when the queries came back fast and verified the index is being used with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`:

```
 Bitmap Heap Scan on parcels  (cost=7.66..25.59 rows=453 width=32) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ("position"(lower(owner1), 'someones name'::text) > 0)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_parcels  (cost=0.00..7.55 rows=453 width=0) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ("position"(lower(owner1), 'someones name'::text) > 0)
 Planning time: 0.075 ms
 Execution time: 0.025 ms
```

Answer (score 4):

You could install [Wildspeed](http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/wiki/wildspeed), a different type of index in PostgreSQL. Wildspeed does work with %word% wildcards, no problem. The downside is the size of the index, this can be large, very large.

Answer (score 4):

When ever you use a clause on a column with functions eg LIKE, ILIKE, upper, lower etc. Then postgres wont take your normal index into consideration. It will do a full scan of the table going through each row and therefore it will be slow.

The correct way would be to create a new index according to your query. For example if i want to match a column without case sensitivity and my column is a varchar. Then you can do it like this.

```
create index ix_tblname_col_upper on tblname (UPPER(col) varchar_pattern_ops);
```

Similarly if your column is a text then you do something like this

```
create index ix_tblname_col_upper on tblname (UPPER(col) text_pattern_ops);
```

Similarly you can change the function upper to any other function that you want.

Answer (score 2):

Please Execute below mentioned query for improve the LIKE query performance in postgresql.
create an index like this for bigger tables:

```
CREATE INDEX <indexname> ON <tablename> USING btree (<fieldname> text_pattern_ops)
```

Comment: This only works if the pattern doesn't start with a wildcard - in this case the first two sample queries both start with a wildcard.

Answer (score 1):

Your like queries probably cannot use the indexes you created because:

1) your LIKE criteria begins with a wildcard.

2) you've used a function with your LIKE criteria.

Answer (score 1):

for what it's worth, **Django** ORM tends to use `UPPER(text)` for all `LIKE` queries to make it case insensitive,

Adding an index on `UPPER(column::text)` has greatly sped up my system, unlike any other thing.

As far as leading %, yes that will not use an index. See this blog for a great explanation:

https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning